# Local mail archiving in Outlook but only on one machine per user

Tags: windows, exchange, outlook

We're looking at implementing local mail archiving for Outlook 2007 the organisation that I work in.

Our initial plan was to roll out a group policy to archive mail to the C: drive. This would work fine for most users but for users that use Outlook on temporary machines (meeting rooms or loan laptops) could have their mail archived into the disks on the temporary machine.

Are there any ways that we might be able to ensure that the archiving only occurs on specified machines for each user (their primary system) without us having to go and configure the archiving on each individual machine.

Could we extract a list of users/computers (via SCCM perhaps) and then use a script to modify the user's profile only enabling archiving on local machines?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the GPO settings that you're using are part of the User Configuration settings, and that you're happy with that solution:

Apply the policy to the Computer account objects (not the user accounts) that you want the policy to apply to, and then enable [Loopback Policy Processing](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/231287) to force the User Configuration settings to be applied to users logging on to those systems. This way, you could exclude shared machines, meeting room machines etc, but it wouldn't cover the situation where someone logs onto someone else's primary machine.